# transpose data based on multiple tables with the help of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for some help for the below. Have 2 big csv files and need to get the data based on few conditions. Here is my sample data file.

```
 a1,a2,v1,v2,v3,v4
 1,12,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 1,13,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 1,145,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 2,15,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 2,169,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 3,164,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 3,147,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 1,174,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 2,148,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
 4,154,12.99,0.0,34.33,0

a1,k1
1,v1
2,v2
3,v3
4,v4
```

The values under a1 and k1 to be matched and if any of the v* are zero,those to be dropped from the final csv file.

```
   a1,a2,v1,v2,v3,v4
   1,12,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
   1,13,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
   1,145,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
   3,164,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
   3,147,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
   1,174,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
```

The values of v2 and v4 are zeroes, so 2 and 4 from A1 rows are dropped.

Thanks in adanvce.

Comment: I don't understand why your last row `2,148,12.99,0.0,34.33,0` remains? When you say *if any of the v* are zero*: do you mean `any` or `all` zero?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
# Find v* columns where all (any?) values are 0
vx_idx = df1.filter(regex=r'^v\d+').eq(0).all().loc[lambda x: x].index

# Find a1 values that match with v*
a1_val = df2.loc[df2['k1'].isin(v), 'a1'].tolist()

# Filter out your final dataframe
out = df1[~df1['a1'].isin(a1_val)]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   a1   a2     v1   v2     v3  v4
0   1   12  12.99  0.0  34.33   0
1   1   13  12.99  0.0  34.33   0
2   1  145  12.99  0.0  34.33   0
5   3  164  12.99  0.0  34.33   0
6   3  147  12.99  0.0  34.33   0
7   1  174  12.99  0.0  34.33   0

>>> print(out.to_csv(index=False))
a1,a2,v1,v2,v3,v4
1,12,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
1,13,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
1,145,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
3,164,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
3,147,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
1,174,12.99,0.0,34.33,0
```